# Facebook Permalink Ending with :0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

> **Note**: This question is not asking how to extract post_id's from the permalink. I'm asking what does the suffix of the permalink
>   actually means/stands for.

I'm working on an app that pulls facebook photos/statuses.

I use a regex to pull the post_id out of a facebook permalink, which normally looks like this:

> https://www.facebook.com/username/posts/post_id

However, from time to time, I notice some permalinks that looks like this:

> https://www.facebook.com/username/posts/post_id:0

Question:
What is ":0"? When/why does it occur?

Edit:
Example of facebook posts:
https://www.facebook.com/hehui.lim/posts/10202967332729156

And..
https://www.facebook.com/lengyein/posts/10152174297949341:0

I also noticed that it is possible to have :1, :2, :3.

Comment: Is it ok if you give a example of the permalink? I noticed this before  but i forgot my note.

Comment: Interesting question... *reserching*

Comment: Which API did you call? For example i can't get this "https://www.facebook.com/lengyein/posts/10152174297949341:0" either i call FQL stream table or via /feed endpoint. So, how did you find out which post allow :0 suffix? I means, how did you find out https://www.facebook.com/lengyein/posts/10152174297949341:0 ?

Comment: This is not an api call. This are permalinks made by Facebook. All you need to do is to mouse over the date of a post, click on it, you'll then come to a page (with only the post) which is the permalink for a status/picture/video etc.

Comment: You means click from the news feed? Because if i click from the page at https://www.facebook.com/lengyein, the date would give me the link to https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10152174132114341&set=a.10151544212989341.1073741835.74485364340&type=1, not https://www.facebook.com/lengyein/posts/10152174297949341:0

Comment: This is my screenshot https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/1476186_10202842136313444_1568714959_n.jpg, you can notice the url on the bottom is a "photo.php?fbid=" link instead of the "/posts/" link.

Comment: If you click on a photo, it's `photo.php?fbid=`. If it's a status, it's `posts/`

Comment: so i guess you are click the post on the newsfeed, because as you can see on my screenshot, no such thing "/posts/" link in the entire page(my mouse is hovering the date).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know the answer.

Credits to Rahil Arora who noticed the sequence.

The scenario is as such:
A photo is being pushed from a third party application (Fb, Instagram, iPhone Gallery, etc) onto your Facebook wall by person A.

Person B is connected to person A.

Person B see's this update on his/her news feed. If B clicks hovers/clicks the timestamp, the relative link will be as the scenario in the question, and everything else is as described in Rahil's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, after looking for such a pattern in some of the posts on my News Feed, I found something worth sharing.

One of my friend uploaded 4 different pictures (from the BlackBerry Smartphone App) **almost at the same time**. All four pictures had a separate Permalink and the message with each post was *'{friend's name} added a new photos'.* That is:

```
https://www.facebook.com/{friend's username}/posts/p_id:0 //Picture 1
https://www.facebook.com/{friend's username}/posts/p_id:1 //Picture 2
https://www.facebook.com/{friend's username}/posts/p_id:2 //Picture 3
https://www.facebook.com/{friend's username}/posts/p_id:3 //Picture 4
```

**And**, Facebook also generated the link:

```
https://www.facebook.com/{friend's username}/posts/p_id
```

which was showing **all the 4 pictures** grouped together and with a message *'{friend's name} added 4 new photos.'* That is, showing all 4 photos in a single post.

So, I guess Facebook uses it to group together the individual photos added by a user, one by one, within a certain period of time difference.

**NOTE**: This is not the same if all the four photos are added together at the same time (I've already tried it).

Comment: I noticed this before. However, it seems that if that person uploaded photos using Facebook's website itself, this pattern wouldn't occur?

Comment: Is it so? In that case, I guess the use of the permalinks are limited to some particular applications.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Added my answer. Thanks for noticing the pattern. :)

Answer (score 1):

I use `explode` for a similar purpose.

refer to: http://www.php.net/explode

```
$str = 'https://www.facebook.com/hehui.lim/posts/10202967332729156:0';
$strEx = explode('/', $str, 6);
$strExId = explode(':', $strEx[5], 2);
echo $strExId[0]; // produces 10202967332729156
```

---

```
Array
(
    [0] => https:
    [1] => 
    [2] => www.facebook.com
    [3] => hehui.lim
    [4] => posts
    [5] => 10202967332729156:0
)
Array
(
    [0] => 10202967332729156
    [1] => 0
)
```

Comment: hi, thanks for answering. but i'm not asking how to get the post id. I'm asking what does ":0", ":1", ":2", etc mean